# Should I use qsort over sort in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, quicksort

I have browsed through most of the questions on the comparison between qsort vs sort in C++. I wanted to just ask if there were any cases where you would prefer qsort over sort?

Comment: The only scenario I can find is when you are stuck with environment, compiler, certifications where you are not allowed to use templates. For example in old avionics embedded projects, etc.

Comment: `qsort(3)` is not a C++ function, but an inherit from C library.  You can use it, as one of the design requirements of C++ implies all C functions are directly available into C++ code.  But if you have it reimplemented in C++, I think it should be better to use it instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably none, std::sort is type safe, plus it can inline the comparator function. The only distinctive strong point of qsort is that it's available in plain C.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data whose size is dynamic yet global, writing a sort for qsort is easier than for sort.

If you have code that already works with qsort, rewriting it can take work.

I haven't found another reason.

Answer (score 1):

qsort requires the comparison function to return negative, zero or positive as an integer, dependent on the ordering. Sort requires a boolean equivalent to the < operator.

Therefore if comparing floating point fields, or non-trivial requirements for structures, qsort() can demand a slightly less efficient and harder to write comparison function. Also, qsort doesn't take a context pointer, it is mpossible to sort in a context-dependent manner (something you only rarely require), without using a global. sort can take a lambda with a capture list. sort() is easier to use and can be more efficient, so is preferable, unless backwards compatibility with C is an issue.